# Proof that $\mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I'm trying to work out the details in a proof that $\mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$. My best attempt at it is below.

> We take for granted that $\mathbb{R} \cong \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \cong 2^{\mathbb{N}}$, so given $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we may identify $x$ with a function $f: \mathbb{N} \to \{0,1\}$, which we may then identify with a sequence $f_n$ in $\{0,1\}$, via the bijective correspondence $f(n) = f_n$. So given a sequence $\{a_m\}$ of real numbers, we identify $a_m$ with a function and, hence, a sequence $f_m$. So there exists a natural correspondence $\{a_m\} \leftrightarrow \{f_{m,n}\}$, where $f_{m,n}$ is the $n$th element in the $m$th sequence. But then there exists a bijective correspondence $g: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to. \{0,1\}$ sending $(m,n) \to f_{m,n}$. As $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \cong \mathbb{N}$, we can also construct a correspondence $g': \mathbb{N} \to \{0,1\}$. The set of $g'$, by definition, is $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$. But then the sequences of bijective maps
> $$ 
> g' \to g \to \{f_{m,n}\}_{m,n \in \mathbb{N}} \to \{a_m\} \to x
> $$
> gives a bijection $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}} \to \mathbb{R}$.

I feel as thought I'm close, but can't finish the proof because I only got a bijection from sequences of $0$'s and $1$'s to $\mathbb{R}$. I suppose I can finish the proof by bijectiong real numbers, and hence real sequences, by binary expansions, but that brings in a question of uniqueness. If I use the non-terminating binary expansions, which I can prove to be unique, that should give the correct bijection.

Comment: dear Stanley, your proof is very nearly there! if you trace your argument through, what you have actually shown is that the set $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ is bijective with the set $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$. but you already know that this latter set is bijective with $\mathbb{R}$! indeed, this latter set is precisely $2^\mathbb{N}$

Comment: here's a slightly cleaner way of thinking about these things, can you show that, for *arbitrary* sets $X$ and $Y$ and $Z$, we have $(X^Y)^Z\cong X^{Y\times Z}$? then, if you know $\mathbb{R}\cong 2^\mathbb{N}$, you can compute $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}\cong (2^{\mathbb{N}})^\mathbb{N}\cong 2^{\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}}$, and then since $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\cong\mathbb{N}$ we have $2^{\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}}\cong 2^\mathbb{N}$, at which point we are done.

Comment: (this is really just a restatement of your proof, but it eliminates some of the technical details by first showing that the relation $(X^Y)^Z\cong X^{Y\times Z}$ holds for arbitrary sets.)

Answer (score 1):

There are many many ways to do this, actually. The most general (and abstract) one is to prove that the axiom of choice is equivalent to the fact that $A \times A \cong A$ for every infinite set $A$. A less abstract way is to use the cantor-Bernstein theorem, which says that if you can find an injection from a set $A$ to a set $B$ and viceversa, then $A \cong B$.

However, the bijection you are using is actually simpler. I am not sure what you are trying to do, but I think it is something like this. Consider that $(0,1 ) \cong \mathbb{R}$, so that we can prove $(0,1) \cong (0,1)^n$. Write a number as 0.xxxxx, its decimal expansion. Then consider the $n$ real numbers constructed this way (I give you an example with $n=3$ instead of writing it down because it's faster and you'll understand anyway):

$$0.123456789 \mapsto (0.147,0.258,0.369)$$

EDIT: I read $\mathbb{R}^n$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, my bad

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I  have a rough idea of how to prove that $\mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{R}^n$, but I'm trying to prove that $\mathbb{R}$ has the same cardinality as sequences of real numbers.

Comment: But in the first line you say you are taking it for granted

Comment: I mean, to every number between 0 and 1 associate its binary rapresentation. Then take a bijection from $(0,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$, for instance some properly rescaled tangent

Comment: Annyway, this question was asked soooo many times, it's probably gonna be marked as duplicate. Check the site

Comment: dear tommy; @StanleySmith is taking for granted that $\mathbb{R}\cong 2^\mathbb{N}$, and what they are trying to show is that $\mathbb{R}\cong \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$; unfortunately your post does not address that question

Comment: Ohhhh I read  $\mathbb{R}^n$  instead of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$